# Windows 11 > Start menu > pinned: Hide names, smaller icons

Tags: windows-11

In Windows 11 > Start menu > pinned items, is there any way to hide the names and get smaller icons (as could be done in Windows 10)?

Here for example I want to hide the words "Word", "Excel", "Powerpoint". I also want the icons to be smaller and closer together (more compact).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 11 Microsoft has removed ALL Start menu customizations,
absolutely all. There is no way to do what you are asking,
at least until perhaps that some future feature release will allow it.

If you wish to go back to the previous Start menu, you need to use a
third-party alternative, such as the free
[Open-Shell](https://github.com/Open-Shell/Open-Shell-Menu)
or the commercial
[Start11](https://www.stardock.com/products/start11/).

Comment: [Open Shell](https://github.com/Open-Shell/Open-Shell-Menu/releases) seems to be for Windows 10 users who want to go back to Windows 7 or earlier versions. It doesn't seem to have been updated for use in Windows 11. (It has also been rarely updated after 2018.)

Comment: The Open-Shell page affirms working on Windows 11. I use it and find it much more useful than the Windows menu. If you want a recently updated version take Start11, it's cheap.

Comment: The problem is that I want to go back to Windows 10 style, but Open Shell doesn't seem to have such an option? Or did I overlook it?

Comment: Open Shell is a better Windows 7 menu. For the Windows 10 look you could try Start11.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the size of icons on the Windows 11 Desktop.

In a blank area of the Desktop, hold the Ctrl Key and roll the mouse wheel.  This allows you to size the Desktop icons.

Start menu icon size (as already noted) cannot be changed.

Taskbar height can be made smaller but that is a hack that does not work well (no damage).

[Taskbar Height](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/change-taskbar-icon-size-windows-11)

> Navigate to
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced.
>
> Create a new DWORD (32-bit) Value by right clicking in the right
> window pane and selecting New->DWORD (32-bit) Value.
>
> Name the value TaskbarSi.
>
> Set the value to one of the following to 0, 1 or 2 which give you
> small, medium or large. You set the value by double clicking on
> TaskbarSi.